# Devel Krumo not updating

Tags: 7, debugging

I have the following code in my module in a hook_form_alter...

```
if($form_id == "privatemsg_new") {
        dsm($form);
        $form['recipient']['#type'] = 'select';
        $form['recipient']['#title'] = 'Choose Recipient';
        unset($form['recipient']['#autocomplete_path']);
    }
```

**The code works just fine, the title is changed, the form field turns into a select list**

However in Krumo, the fields are not being updated. I guess its not the end of the world, but its annoying to not be able to see my changes!

[image]

Type, Title and #autocomplete_path should all have changed.

I've run cron, flushed caches etc. Anything else I can try?

Comment: Because you run `dsm()` before your change. You just put `dsm()` to the end, it would work..

Comment: You need to take a snap to fresh your brain. :)

Comment: I need a holiday! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `dsm()` to the end of code...

```php
if ($form_id == "privatemsg_new") {
  $form['recipient']['#type'] = 'select';
  $form['recipient']['#title'] = 'Choose Recipient';
  unset($form['recipient']['#autocomplete_path']);
  dsm($form);
}
```